# Conceptual Question: Shared GraphQL schema for multiple endpoints (client/admin)

Tags: graphql, nestjs, monorepo

**Context**
I am using a NX Workspace to organize two different angular frontends (client & admin). To separate client and admin logic, two different NestJS backend services including GraphQL are used for client and admin.
As both services fetch data from a single MongoDB a single database library is used for both frontends.

[image]

Both backend services currently use a single GraphQL Schema generated through schema-first approach and a single database layer. In most cases the types and fields definition matches between client and admin, but in some cases a single service requires additional query arguments or fields.
For example, the admin service depends on the fields `confirmed` or `banned` of type `User` while they shouldn't be available through the client service.
Furthermore, e.g. the `getUsers` query should not be exposed through the client service.

```
type User {
    _id: ID
    name: String
    email: String

    confirmed: Boolean
    banned: Boolean
}

type Query {
    getUserById(userId: String): User
    getUsers(): [User]
}
```

**Question**
Are there any best practices how to proceed with the GraphQL Schema(s) in such a case as the types are almost similar.

Answer (score 0):

You can use schema directives to define authorization rules in a declarative manner directly in your Graphql schema.

A common approach would be to assign roles to a user and then use these roles to allow/block access to certain mutations or queries.

So for your example, I would imagine any request coming from the `client` would be made by a user with a role of `client` and any request coming from admin would have a user role of `admin`

So to build on your example of limiting the `getUsers` query to just `admins` we could add this directive to our schema:

```
type User {
    _id: ID
    name: String
    email: String

    confirmed: Boolean
    banned: Boolean
}

type Query {
    getUserById(userId: String): User 
    getUsers(): [User] @hasRole(roles: [admin])
}
```

You can read more about how to actually implement the custom directive `hasRoles` in the nestJs docs https://docs.nestjs.com/graphql/directives

Comment: Do you have any recommendations for structuring the schema(s) and resolver(s) in this case of a multi-client graphql server?
Should the `ClientService` and `AdminService` in the above example be merged into a single graphql endpoint, or would you suggest using a microservice architecture for the different entities `User`, `Foo`, `Bar` including a federation gateway?